# Display a subset of model data in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have the following in my routes

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.query('post',{published:true});
    }
});
```

and a post-viewer component that renders the model. the problem that i am facing with is `filter`. How can i implement the same without loading the models each time. Currently i am just passing the models in the component and using the following

```
{{#each posts as |item|}}
{{/each}}
```

To render the elements. What is the proper way by which lets say i can filter them based on title containing some specific keyword. I tried using `this.store.query` inside the each loop but that did not work out.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `this.store.query` ember [does not cache the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009059/how-to-cache-query-result-in-ember-data). So probably you should use a `.findAll()` and then filter the data on the client side. A simple way to do so is inside your `model()` hook:

```
return this.store.findAll('post')
  .then(posts => posts.filter(post => get(post, 'published') === true));
```

This will work because ember-data does cache the result of the `findAll()` and the filter executes on the client. You can do the same with a computed property. This has some benefits, as, for example, you can filter based on another property. A computed property in your controller for example:

```
filteredModel: Ember.computed('model.@each.name', 'searchName', {
  get() {
    return get(this, 'model').filter(record => get(record, 'name') === get(this, 'searchName'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers

and [filter](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#filter)/[filterBy](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#filter-by)

**filter** -Filters an array by a callback.

```
{{#each (filter (action "isActive") users) as |user|}}
  {{user.name}} is active!
{{/each}}
```

**filter-by** Filters an array by a property.

```
{{#each (filter-by "isActive" true users) as |user|}}
  {{user.name}} is active!
{{/each}}
```

If you omit the second argument it will test if the property is truthy.

```
{{#each (filter-by "address" users) as |user|}}
  {{user.name}} has an address specified!
{{/each}}
```

You can also pass an action as second argument:

```
{{#each (filter-by "age" (action "olderThan" 18) users) as |user|}}
  {{user.name}} is older than eighteen!
{{/each}}
```

**P.S.**
Another variant ( pure Ember.js ) - create computed property and iterate over it. And inside computed property filter items